# Error when generating signed APK in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, error-handling, proguard, release

> Warning:retrofit2.-KotlinExtensions: can’t find referenced class
>   org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your ProGuard

```
-keep class org.jetbrains.annotations.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.jetbrains.annotations.**
```

Comment: Thank you my friend but this code does not work unfortunately. In the gradle console on this line it does not go on ...:
:app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease

Answer (score 0):

The warning appeared also on my side after I've updated the buildToolsVersion from 28.0.3 to 29.0.0.

Comment: I'm on 29.0.2 and still get it :(